# How to find the limit of the below function

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the Limit of the function when $x \to \frac{\pi}2$

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2}(\sin x)^{\sec^2 x}$$

I have tried the  above by taking logarithm however the series goes on. Can you please give some shortcut or tip to solve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make life easier, let $x=\frac \pi 2+y$ making $$\lim_{x \to \pi/2}(\sin (x))^{\sec^2 (x)}=\lim_{y \to 0}(\cos (y))^{\csc^2 (y)}$$ Now
$$A=(\cos (y))^{\csc^2 (y)}\implies \log(A)=\csc^2 (y)\log(\cos (y))$$ and now, Taylor series $$\cos(y)=1-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{24}+O\left(y^6\right)$$ $$\log(\cos (y))=-\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^4}{12}+O\left(y^6\right)$$ $$\csc(y)=\frac{1}{y}+\frac{y}{6}+\frac{7 y^3}{360}+O\left(y^5\right)$$ $$\csc^2(y)=\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{y^2}{15}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ $$\log(A)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{y^2}{4}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ $$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}-\frac{y^2}{4 \sqrt{e}}+O\left(y^3\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}-\frac{\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2}{4
   \sqrt{e}}+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^3\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Just for the fun, try using $x=\frac \pi 3$; the value of the initial expression is $\frac{9}{16}=0.5625$ while the above approximation gives $\frac{144-\pi ^2}{144 \sqrt{e}}\approx 0.564960$.

Comment: @AjeezMohd. May I confess (once more) that I felt in love with Taylor (series) sixty years ago and thet series composition is one of my hobbies ? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

By L'hopital.

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2}\frac{\ln (\sin x)}{\cos^2 x}=\lim_{x \to \pi/2}\frac{ (\cos x)}{\sin x(2\cos x)(-\sin x)}$$

Comment: which means the answer is e^(-1/2) ? because we can't take natural lograthm directly on Right hand side alone. Is the answer for the question e^(-1/2) or just (-1/2)

Comment: The exponent is there for the initial question. exponent is the inverse for logarithm. p/s: you might want to include what you obtain explicitly for your next post.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (without using log):
$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2}(\sin x)^{\sec^2 x}=\lim_{x \to \pi/2}(1+(\sin x-1))^{\frac{1}{\sin x=1}\cdot \frac{\sin x-1}{\cos^2 x}}=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to \pi/2} \frac{\sin x-1}{\cos^2 x}\right) \stackrel{L'Hospital}=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to \pi/2} \frac{\cos x}{2\cos x (-\sin x)}\right)=\exp\left(-\frac12 \right)=e^{-1/2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the technique of "making life easier" as suggested by user "Claude Leibovici" and put $x=(\pi/2)-t$ to transform the given limit into $\lim_{t\to 0}(\cos t)^{\operatorname {cosec}^{2}t}$. If $L$ is the desired limit then $$\log L=\log\lim_{t\to 0}(\cos t) ^{\operatorname {cosec} ^{2}t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\log (\cos t) ^{\operatorname {cosec} ^{2}t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log \cos t} {\sin^{2}t}$$ The last limit can be evaluated easily as $$\log L=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log\cos t} {\cos t-1}\cdot\frac{\cos t-1}{t^{2}}\cdot\frac{t^{2}}{\sin^{2}t}=1\cdot(-1/2)\cdot 1=-\frac{1}{2}$$ and thus $L=1/\sqrt{e}$.